# What's the ost that starts playing at 7:20 episode 7 in MHA Season 5?

Tags: music, my-hero-academia

What's the ost that starts playing at 7:20 episode 7 in MHA Season 5 ?
the song that starts with **moori moori moori**

Comment: Welcome to Anime & Manga! Please include a YouTube video link to the said episode (which includes the song, of course) in order to make things easier/more efficient for people trying to answer your question.

Answer (score 1):

Its 騎馬戦 of 林ゆうき (yuki Hayashi)